# Eliminating an activity from original source code

Tags: android

To be brief, I have this android app's source code that has two main activities A and B, and what I'm trying to do is keeping only the A activity and eliminating the B without having to rewrite the code from the beginning.

Any tips to help?

Comment: You have to make some changes at application. For example you can delete Activity B and then delete references that need Activity B.

Comment: I did try to delete the B activity, but before I had to detect all Usages of the activity and had to remove the lines from code, but when I try to run app it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the error write stacktrace.